# Mutate-like operation for converting string and rolling mean in Julia

Tags: julia

I understand how to convert string and work out a moving average in a line by line approach. But I am wondering how to do them through a mutate-like approach in a pipe style.

```
julia> first(d1, 10)
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ Year   Exports          
     │ Int64  String           
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │  1960  12.9944524843222
   2 │  1961  12.4031007751938
   3 │  1962  13.9430116004055
   4 │  1963  13.0058857232148
   5 │  1964  14.9382483265768
   6 │  1965  13.220177939017
   7 │  1966  12.9323802481308
   8 │  1967  12.8837295006449
   9 │  1968  12.2976680384088
  10 │  1969  11.9548596244419


d1.Exports = parse.(Float64, d1.Exports)
d1.Exports_4mv = runmean(d1.Exports, 4)
```

I wish to get something like this:

```
@linq d1 |>
    mutate(:Exports = parse.(Float64, :Exports)) |>
    mutate(:Exports_4mv = runmean(:Exports, 4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DataFrames.jl you can do (I use `-x` function instead of `runmean` as I am not sure which package you took `runmean` function from):

```
julia> using DataFrames, Chain, DataFramesMeta

julia> d1 = DataFrame(Year=1960:1969, Exports=string.(10rand(10) .+ 10))
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ Year   Exports
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │  1960  18.487768691740964
   2 │  1961  19.16038389519686
   3 │  1962  19.393969741723705
   4 │  1963  10.98014563868417
   5 │  1964  13.971724415708335
   6 │  1965  15.013359289888458
   7 │  1966  10.571278054318459
   8 │  1967  10.193140593100727
   9 │  1968  12.768467572044944
  10 │  1969  14.404484209802783

julia> @chain d1 begin
       transform(:Exports => ByRow(x -> parse(Float64, x)) => :Exports)
       transform(:Exports => (x -> -x) => :Exports_4mv)
       end
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Year   Exports  Exports_4mv
     │ Int64  Float64  Float64
─────┼─────────────────────────────
   1 │  1960  18.4878     -18.4878
   2 │  1961  19.1604     -19.1604
   3 │  1962  19.394      -19.394
   4 │  1963  10.9801     -10.9801
   5 │  1964  13.9717     -13.9717
   6 │  1965  15.0134     -15.0134
   7 │  1966  10.5713     -10.5713
   8 │  1967  10.1931     -10.1931
   9 │  1968  12.7685     -12.7685
  10 │  1969  14.4045     -14.4045
```

and with DataFramesMeta.jl 0.7 release:

```
julia> @chain d1 begin
       @transform(Exports = parse.(Float64, :Exports))
       @transform(Exports_4mv = -:Exports)
       end
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Year   Exports  Exports_4mv
     │ Int64  Float64  Float64
─────┼─────────────────────────────
   1 │  1960  18.4878     -18.4878
   2 │  1961  19.1604     -19.1604
   3 │  1962  19.394      -19.394
   4 │  1963  10.9801     -10.9801
   5 │  1964  13.9717     -13.9717
   6 │  1965  15.0134     -15.0134
   7 │  1966  10.5713     -10.5713
   8 │  1967  10.1931     -10.1931
   9 │  1968  12.7685     -12.7685
  10 │  1969  14.4045     -14.4045
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks. I think the DataFramesMeta.jl is easier for my mental loading :)

Comment: Yes - it is easier and that is why it exits (at the cost of having non standard syntax, while DataFrames.jl code is a fully valid Julia syntax).